# Join many lists using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

What would be a slick way to join many lists together, using list comprehension or otherwise

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> c = [7,8,9]
>>> d = [x for x in a or b or c]
>>> d
[1, 2, 3]
```

This doesn't quite work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> a + b + c
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [y for x in (a,b,c) for y in x]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Using [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(a,b,c))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another solution:

```
>>> sum([a,b,c],[])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
d=a+b+c
```

It sums the lists together.

Or, you can do this:

```
>>> d=[]
>>> for l in (a,b,c): d.extend(l)
```